# Problems with my TTYs key bindings in Fedora 38

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, tty, terminal-emulator

I am trying to configure my `.inputrc` file as I always did for key bindings (bash and Fedora 38). It works perfectly for urxvt/xterm, but my TTY's (virtual consoles) do not take into account modifiers. I mean, if i press `C-V + Delete` I see the same as `C-V C-Delete`, and the same for all other keys.

Why is this, and how to fix it?

And which is the binding for going up/down 1 page in the buffer, to see lines that already disappeared? Was this removed?

**EDIT:**

Following @egmont advice, I called `showkey -a` in a TTY confirming the above: the modifiers do not affect `Delete`, `PageUp` and `PageDown` keys, same bytes are generated. xterm/urxvt work normally, with the `showkey -a` showing different codes with the modifiers.

The bash shell command `bind -l` does not show anything resembling pageup/down in the terminal buffer, so it seems that it has been removed; this was removed in Fedora 36 but only after logout, now it seems it was completely removed (maybe because security?). So it seems there is no more virtual terminal buffers accessible from the shell...?

Comment: As for `C-V C-Delete` and friends, it could really help if you showed us your `.inputrc`. Also, run `showkey -a` on the console to see what bytes these keypresses produce.

Comment: `.inputrc` configures your _shell_, whereas scrolling back by 1 page in the buffer is a feature of the _terminal_.

Comment: Yes, and I always used the shell command to access this terminal feature. It seems it has been removed? Please see the Edit.

Comment: There's no way any application running inside the terminal, including the shell, could instruct the terminal to scroll back in its buffers. It's a private business of _terminals_ which they typically tie to Shift+PgUp / Shift+PgDown, and they do _not_ expose it via escape sequences. You most certainly remember incorrectly, maybe you mix it up with some other feature, or mistakenly believed an irrelevant line of `.inputrc` to have that effect. (I'm a former co-developer of a very popular terminal emulator and also keep a close eye on bash/readline features and changes, so trust me.)

Comment: If modifiers don't make a difference on the console, as shown by `showkey -a`, then there's nothing the shell could do to differentiate them. You need to look at the keymap loaded for the console, probably around the command `loadkeys` from the `console-setup` package, although details might vary across distributions. For me, on Ubuntu, they generate different keycodes. My knowledge about console setup is quite outdated so sorry, I can't help you on how to set up a proper one that generates different bytes or escape sequences.

Comment: I trust you, I got it. I use the very same sequence since I began using Linux many years ago, and it was `Shift + PageUp/Down`, and likely you are right and it was not because of the corresponding lines in the `.inputrc` (I did not know this). But now it does not work anymore. My guess the virtual terminal removed the `Shift + PageUp/Down` binding because of security... but it is just a guess. I will try to play with `loadkeys` to solve the problem: how to see the terminal buffers (regardless of the key sequences). Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what happened to Shift+PgUp/Dn in the console. Regardless, my personal recommendation: Use a graphical environment with a graphical terminal emulator. They are just superior in almost every way. Nicer fonts, better Unicode coverage, more colors, more attributes, hyperlink autodetection, copy-paste across graphical apps and terminal, resize as you please, much larger scrollback buffer with an actual scrollbar, much faster, tab support, no need to log in for each and every new terminal, and so on and so forth. IMO the console should be used for emergency firefigthing only. (YMMV.)

Comment: Actually, I am mistaken: `Shift + PageUp/Down` now does nothing, it is not like `PageUp/Down` alone. Yet `Ctrl + PageUp/Down` and `Alt + PageUp/Down` give the same bytes as `PageUp/Down` alone.

Comment: Yes, I agree completely. I do use a graphical environment (KDE) with graphical terminals (urxvt's). But sometimes I need to use TTYs when I do not want to touch my KDE, or when it fails for some reason. I don´t have any problems in KDE or with `urxvt`, only with the virtual consoles.